# Call javascript after choosing from Bootstrap Dropdown

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

All Bootstrap Dropdown menu examples show the items having an  link like:

```
    <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
```

How can I make a Bootstrap dropdown menu where choosing an item triggers a javascript method?

(If it makes a difference, the menu items will also be added to the menu using javascript/jquery initially)

Is this just a matter of adding a click function to each `<li>`? Or does Bootstrap provide special handling for its dropdown items?

If I add a click function, do I still need each item to also have the `<a href="#">` tag around the text?

Comment: how about adding an event listener to the menu item in question? What have you tried?

Comment: Downvoters -- is this question just too elementary, or is there something I can fix?

Comment: Not a downvoter, but it seems unclear what you're asking. Are you wanting to attach a click function to the links in your list?

Comment: I'm wondering if I need a "basic" click function or if bootstrap provides some special handling.  Also do I need to keep the <a> tag if I add a click function?  Will edit the question.

Comment: Could this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation Seen as you are using JavaScript/jQuery anyway.

Comment: @spaceman - maybe, it looks promising

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the answer is:

- Bootstrap does not supply any special handling for clicks on its
  dropdown menu items; and
- I could add a click function to each item in the list; or
- I could use [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation) to add the click function to the list
  itself, and it will be triggered on each child's click

Thanks to @Pevara and @spaceman for getting me rolling.

Comment: Sample code would be great

Comment: Sorry @Nick.McDermaid this question is almost 6 years old, I don't have have the code anymore or even use Bootstrap anymore.